# python - setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I decided to create a small little module named "NsmPY". Once I had finished the code behind the module (available on GitHub), I got to work trying to upload this new module to PyPi. However, when I ran the necessary command `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, the program spat out an error:

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing nsmpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to nsmpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to nsmpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'nsmpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'nsmpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt, README.md

running check
creating nsmpy-1.0
creating nsmpy-1.0\nsmpy.egg-info
copying files to nsmpy-1.0...
copying setup.cfg -> nsmpy-1.0
copying setup.py -> nsmpy-1.0
copying nsmpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> nsmpy-1.0\nsmpy.egg-info
copying nsmpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> nsmpy-1.0\nsmpy.egg-info
copying nsmpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> nsmpy-1.0\nsmpy.egg-info
copying nsmpy.egg-info\top_level.txt -> nsmpy-1.0\nsmpy.egg-info
Writing nsmpy-1.0\setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'nsmpy-1.0' (and everything under it)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_scripts
creating build
creating build\scripts-3.7
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nsmpy'
```

However, in my code there is absolutely no mention of the file or directory 'nsmpy', and even so, the code, setup.py, setup.cfg and all other setup files are all stored in the folder 'nsmpy'.

Furthermore, when I finally did upload this to my account on PyPi (I ran `python setup.py sdist`) it did work - until I actually decided to install the module with `pip install nsmpy`, it gave me the following errors:

```
Collecting nsmpy==1.0.0
  Using cached nsmpy-1.0.tar.gz (628 bytes)
Building wheels for collected packages: nsmpy
  Building wheel for nsmpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mm6p5lwl'
       cwd: C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-98ihityv\nsmpy\
  Complete output (6 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_scripts
  creating build
  creating build\scripts-3.7
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nsmpy'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for nsmpy
  Running setup.py clean for nsmpy
Failed to build nsmpy
ERROR: Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3021, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3012, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 517, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 114, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 53, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2736, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3023, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3032, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3014, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1420, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(path)
  File "c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1616, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\sciencepi\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow-2.1.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
Installing collected packages: nsmpy
    Running setup.py install for nsmpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ap1k2wf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\Include\nsmpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-98ihityv\nsmpy\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_scripts
    creating build
    creating build\scripts-3.7
    error: file 'C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-98ihityv\nsmpy\nsmpy' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SCIENC~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-98ihityv\\nsmpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SCIENC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9ap1k2wf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sciencepi\anaconda3\Include\nsmpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

And yes, I am using the latest modules and latest versions of everything.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="nsmpy",
    version="1.0.0",
    scripts=['nsmpy'])
```

Comment: How does the `setup.py` file looks like?

Comment: honestly, some people just dislike posts because they can; this is an issue stackoverflow needs to sort out.

Comment: I downvoted, because in short: the question has not much value to the larger community, it only helps solving one particular issue, that barely anyone else is likely to have (since it's a typo), and if they did they would be unlikely to find this post from a search engine. Downvotes should not be seen as a punishment, often they just mean the question (and their answers) are unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: in which case >90% of all questions on this site would have a vote rating of -20. Also, this was not a typo, and I feel quite strongly that every post has a purpose, thus people with this problem are likely to get help from this post. When you downvote, it makes the post less accessible to those who need it.

Comment: Well, another issue with your comment is that stackoverflow _is_ a website for solving issues.

Comment: The entire point of a question, no matter how insignificant, is to help whomever asked it, and to help those with a similar issue. This question also was not _poorly researched_, the reason I asked it was because I had done the research and there were no other instances of this error. Therefore your comment is not valid and will be flagged.

Comment: Same root issue, different symptoms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531367/11138259

Comment: We should not down-vote a question based on whether there is a value for it or not. SO is often a place where we can find even the most niche scenarios. I would, however, down-voted it because it says nothing in the title. SO has a field for tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scripts` parameter of `setuptools.setup` function should be a list of filenames. So in your case I believe it should read:

```
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    scripts=['nsmpy.py'],
    # ...
)
```

Also note that the `scripts` parameter has somewhat fallen out of favor. It is nowadays recommended to use `console_scripts` *entry points* instead, for which there is much more up-to-date documentation available.

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts
- https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation