# Pip install from git repository, errors due to wrong quotes

Tags: python, windows, git, pip, quoting

## Problem Description

Using Python 3.7.6 on Windows 10, I'm trying to upgrade a package installed directly from a git repository:

`pip install --upgrade git+https://url.of.my/py/package.git`

The installation then fails:

```
...
error: file 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ip4k0pfs\bin\some-script' does not exist
...
```

As far as I've been able to work out, for the following reason: early on, pip calls

`git clone -q https://url.of.my/py/package.git 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ip4k0pfs'`

i.e. it checks out the repository into a temporary directory. However, the directory isn't created and no sources are checked out. Indeed, when I run the command on the Windows command line (I've also tried Git Bash and MSYS2 Bash, same problem), I get an error:

```
C:\Users\myuser>git clone -q https://url.of.my/py/package.git 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ip4k0pfs'
fatal: could not create leading directories of ''C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ip4k0pfs'': Invalid argument
```

The problem are the *single* quotes around the path to the temporary directory. Changing them to double quotes makes the error disappear:

```
C:\Users\myuser>git clone -q https://url.of.my/py/package.git "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ip4k0pfs"
```

## Question

Is there any way to tell pip to use double instead of single quotes? Any other ideas for how to overcome this problem?

## Edits

1. In the meantime, I've also tried Python 3.8.2 with pip 20.1, and got the same error

Comment: you may spin an instance of linux on aws and see if your package is broken, or is it just windows problem

Comment: I doubt the issue lies in the quotes. I would rather look into the issue with the `error: file 'C:\...\bin\some-script' does not exist`. What is this script, is it part of the project being installed? Is it properly packaged? Is it in the git repository?

Comment: @sinoroc You were right, the quotes — or rather, the fact that the logged `git` command doesn't work if directly executed — were a red herring, and the actual problem was that my `setup.py` had a typo in one of the `scripts` it claimed to publish. Feel free to post a short, corresponding answer, I'll accept it then. If not, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Glad, a solution was found. I'm fine with you answering your own question, I wouldn't know what to write exactly, since it was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

As @sinoroc suspected, the quotes — or rather, the fact that the logged git command doesn't work if directly executed — were a red herring, and the actual problem was that my `setup.py` had a typo: the `scripts` list included a file named `bin/some-script`, which was actually named `bin/some-script.py`, and thus couldn't be found.

Comment: Same root issue, different symptoms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322989/11138259

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and did not have the same underlying issue. The issue is resolved by using git bash (MINGW), which handles the quotes correctly.